# Apache HttpAsyncClient memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpasyncclient

I need to use HttpAsyncClient under the high load. I create HttpAsyncClient like this:

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT)
        .setSocketTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(CONNECTION_REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
        .build();
HttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(createRequestConfig())
        .build();
```

And then I use it like this:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestBody, "UTF-8"));
client.execute(request, null)
```

Usually I don't really care about response, so I don't initialize `Future<HttpResponse>` variable and don't do `Future.get()`. Well, just for the clarification (I don't think it has something to do with question), I care about responses sometimes, but 99% of responses are not interesting for me.

The problem is when I do a lot of requests (for instance 300 every second, and by "request" word here I mean `client.execute()` invokation) I finally get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`. I tried to use VisualVM to find out what's happening. I see that `java.lang.Object[]`, `char[]`, `java.lang.String`, `byte[]`, `short`, `char[]` instances count is growing (I tried to force GC and to limit heap size to be sure it isn't normal - didn't help). And so is growing the used heap space.

What causes this problem? Maybe I should use `HttpAsyncClient` some different way? Do I need to use custom `RequestProducer`, `ResponseProducer` or to use `CountDownLatch`?

**UPD**
The problem was because of PowerMock library

Comment: How many `HttpAsyncClient` instances you have?

Comment: I mean, do you create `client` for each requests or not?

Comment: No, ofc not, I have only one `client`

Comment: Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775618/httpclient-4-0-1-how-to-release-connection You will find resolution in this topic.

Comment: Connection management in the classic and async HCs are completely different. Everything what has been said in 4775618 bears no relevance for HttpAsyncClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that I were using PowerMock to run my tests. Without PowerMock everything works fine.

Answer (score 4):

HttpAsyncClient does not throttle request execution rate in any way or fashion to avoid blocking of the #execute method. One can submit boundless number of requests to the client and the client will dutifully stick them all into the execution queue. How fast those requests can actually be executed and removed from the queue is a whole different story and can depend on many factors. In your particular case you are trying to process all those requests with just 2 concurrent connections per route, which may not necessarily the optimal thing to do.

PS: /**old man's grumbling**/ people should not presume that async clients would be somehow faster for some reason. They will not be unless used for specific use cases and in a specific manner. What is certain that one can easily end up using more memory with async clients unless very careful.

Comment: "does not throttle request execution rate in any way or fashion to avoid blocking of the #execute method" - cound you please explain it a little more? I was thinking about these requests queue inside client too. But here is the thing - I set `connectionRequestTimeout` so I thought I can be sure that if request in queue don't get it's own connection in 5 seconds, it is cancelled with `TimeoutException`. But somehow it looks like GC can't clean something inside client.

Comment: Some offtop about performance: in my case first advantage of using async client is that thread won't be blocked; and second, maybe, pipelining support. Ofc I could create some kind of facade over the synchronous client, but it would be much harder - cancellation support, some other specific features etc

Comment: Instead of guessing you should find out what exactly does not get cleaned up.

Comment: Any ideas how could I check it? I've took a look at `HttpAsyncClient`'s source code and can't really find out what could not be erased. As far as I understand `InternalHttpAsyncClient` (it's the implementation I use at the moment) creates a new `DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl` and starts it. It tries to get the connection from the pool until the timeout is reached. And there I can't see any problems that could lead to obsolete references or something. Anyway seems like there aren't any API I can control this outside with. Am I using `HttpAsyncClient` right in my question?

Comment: I've wrote a simple load test: http://pastebin.com/0XaquW35 . Here is the part of output: http://pastebin.com/ykCyJNHY . It was unexpected for me that none of the requests have been executed. If I sleep 1000ms every iteration in my test, it works perfectly fine. It's a strange way that `HttpAsyncClient` manage requests. Considering that old requests are being removed from execution queue after `connectionRequest` timeout I can't understand is there any chance that queue size is growing constantly. Btw, by `execution queue` phrase you meant many instances of `DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl`?

Comment: It's just for instance, I needed responsive host for this sample test. Could you take a look at another questions please?

Comment: Why? What is the point in me telling you that one should be using a profiler or memory analyzer when investigating a potential memory leak?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to profile it again. Well as far as I understand my problem is about `HttpAsyncClient` cannot manage too many requests and "chokes". I just found your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101865/how-to-configure-the-number-of-allowed-pending-requests-in-apache-async-client think it's what I need, I'll try tomorrow

Comment: HttpAsyncClient does exactly what your code instructs it to do. Your problem is that you do not seem to have a clear idea what you are trying to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100935/discussion-between-coolguy-and-oleg).